# Querying with model associations in ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Model A has_many Model B. I want to return all Model As with certain types of Model Bs.

For example, I want to return all Users who have both a Vehicle of type Ford and a Vehicle of type Chevrolet (Ford and Chevrolet are properties of the Vehicle model)

I can easily query to find all users who have a ford or all users who have a chevy but I don't want to do 2 queries and then intersect the results. Instead I want to perform only 1 query. How do I combine this into 1 query?

Comment: Could you show us the code you already have? It'll make it easier to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
User.joins([:vehicles, :vehicles]).
     where("vehicles.model = ? AND vehicles_users.model = ?", "Ford", "Chevy")
```

**Solution 2**

Supports arbitrary models.

```
models = ["Ford", "Chevy"]
User.where(:id => User.joins(:select => "users.id", :vehicles).
  where(:vehicles => {:model => models}).group("users.id").
  having("COUNT(*) = #{models.size}").limit(30)
)
```

[Reference 1](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/07/oracle-vs-mysql-vs-sql-server.html)

**Solution 3**

Slower solution, in case you needed one..

```
User.where([
"EXISTS (
   SELECT A.* 
   FROM vehicles A 
   WHERE A.user_id = users.id AND 
         A.model = ?) AND 
 EXISTS (
   SELECT B.* 
   FROM vehicles B 
   WHERE B.user_id = users.id AND 
         B.model = ?)
 ", "Ford", "Chevy"
])
```

Comment: Great, this worked! Thank you! One other question - say I want to run a similar query but instead of looking for users who have a ford and chevy, I want to find users who have all of an arbitrary set of cars (for example a ford & chevy & ferrari & mazerati, etc.). How do I perform such a query where the size of the set varies?

Comment: I have compacted the original solution.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was previously using a solution with eval() but this is much better!

Comment: One other question now - this query works fine on local but not on production. Query:  SELECT "tutors".* FROM "tutors" INNER JOIN "expertises" ON "expertises"."tutor_id" = "tutors"."id" WHERE ("expertises"."subject_id" IN (9)) GROUP BY tutors.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ORDER BY rank DESC):

gives me this error on production

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  column "tutors.fname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

even though it works on local. Production is heroku is running postgreSQL and locally I am running a sqllite database.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have restricted the result set to 30. If you want to paginate the results add the pagination to the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** To get users with both vehicles Ford and Chevrolet, you can do this:

```
User.     
  select("DISTINCT users.*").
  joins("INNER JOIN vehicles AS v1 ON v1.user_id = users.id").
  joins("INNER JOIN vehicles AS v2 ON v2.user_id = users.id").
  where("v1.type" => "Ford", "v2.type" => "Chevrolet").
```

**Edit 2:** Or, if you prefer having clean code and can tolerate 2 queries:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_vehicule, lambda { |type| joins(:vehicles).where(:type => type) }
  # ...
end

users_with_both = User.with_vehicle("Ford").to_a & User.with_vehicle("Chevrolet").to_a
```

**Old answer** (to retrieve users with any of the two types):

```
User.joins(:vehicle).where(:vehicles => {:type => ["Ford", "Chevrolet"]})
```

Or (I'm not sure what "properties" means in your question):

```
User.joins(:vehicle).where("vehicles.ford = 1 OR vehicles.chevrolet = 1")
```

Comment: He wants users who have BOTH a Ford and a Chevvy. Not either.

Comment: yes, that's correct. BOTH. Is it possible to do this at the database or do I have to take an array of records where duplicate records indicate BOTH and then parse these records to eliminate records that are not duplicates (or triplicates if I have 3 vehicles)